# Subdomain https www to non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have a domain called `example.com` and within this domain are two sub-domains called:

- `qa1.example.com`
- `qa2.example.com`

All of which have SSL certification. However, I have a `.htaccess` file as follows:

### UPDATED

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log|xml)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
```

The following happens:

1. `http://qa1.example.com` > redirects to > `https://qa1.example.com`
2. `http://www.qa1.example.com` > redirects to > `https://www.qa1.example.com`
3. `https://www.qa1.example.com` > redirects to > `https://www.qa1.example.com`

Number 1 is correct, but numbers 2 and 3 need to redirect to `https://qa1.example.com` without the `www`.

How can this be achieved? I can include the `.htaccess` file separately for the two sub-domains.

Comment: There isn't really a #3 - _nothing_ happens in this instance - no redirect.

Comment: "I can include the .htaccess file separately for the two sub-domains." - Just noticed your last comment, are you saying you have a different `.htaccess` file for each subdomain?

Comment: Yes I do have a separate file for each sub-domain. Should I rather add one file to the root domain?

Comment: It depends what the `.htaccess` files for the subdomains are doing? Are the subdomains pointing to subdirectories off the main domains document root, or are they entirely separate? I have assumed in my answer that all subdomains are canonicalised/controlled by the single .htaccess in the document root. If you have a separate `.htaccess` file for the subdomain, containing mod_rewrite directives then the above `.htaccess` file is not being used at all in this instance.

Comment: They are separate and does not point to anything of the main domain. They are two completely different website instances.

Comment: Ah OK, so what is the `.htaccess` code you have added to your question? The main domain or the subdomain?

Comment: The code I added is for the sub-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
> ```

Your canonical HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www redirects should come *before* your internal rewrites (routing directives). After the `RewriteBase` directive.

Try the following:

```
# www to non-www canonicalisation (including subdomains)
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrites / routing goes here...
```

If you didn't have additional subdomains it would be relatively trivial to combine these into one rule. Also, this should be a `301` (permanent) redirect, rather than a `302` (temporary), which is what the `R` flag will default to. (However, it can be easier to test with temporary redirects as they aren't cached by the browser.)

**UPDATE:** The above directives were assuming these were going in your main domains `.htaccess` file and the subdomains were all controlled from this (in subdirectories off the main domain's document root). They should still work OK for the subdomains `.htaccess` file, however, they could be optimised into a single rule (at most one redirect, rather than two). For example:

```
# www to non-www and HTTP to HTTPS canonicalisation
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://qa1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above obviously hardcodes the hostname for the subdomain. If you have only two subdomains then that shouldn't be a problem. It is certainly *safer*.

To generalise the above, you can use the `SERVER_NAME` variable. However, you need to ensure that `UseCanoncialName On` is first set in your server config (default is `Off`), otherwise this will simply hold the hostname from the request (which is part of the problem you're seeing in your question). The `ServerName` directive also needs to be set to the correct subdomain. eg. `ServerName qa1.example.com`.

```
# www to non-www and HTTP to HTTPS canonicalisation
# UseCanonicalName On - must be set in server config
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to the subdomains `.htaccess` file. However, my initial answer would have still worked OK (which I've left in place) - it just may not have been optimal.

Comment: I have updated the htaccess code above with the full code, its still not working.. tried your edits and it goes into an infinite loop of redirects.

Comment: The updated `.htaccess` code you've added to the question is different to what I've posted above. You've used `HTTP_HOST` in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ - yes, that will definitely result in a redirect loop. (But you've also used `RewriteRule` where it should be `RewriteCond` in the line above.) (?) You will also need to make sure that the browser cache is clear before testing these redirects - since any erroneous 301 redirects will have been cached by the browser.